# Get BindingFlags from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have an object obtained through a call to `Type.GetProperty()` and I would like to know the combination of binding flags used to retrieve it.

When I inspect the object in the debugger, I can see it is a `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo` with a `BindingFlags` property containing the value I need. However, it seems that is an internal type because the compiler does not recognise it as a valid data type. Instead, it views the value returned by `Type.GetProperty()` as a `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` which, funnily enough, does not contain a `BindingFlags` property.

Can anybody suggest a reference I might add to the project in order for the compiler to understand the type `System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo`, or maybe an alternative way to obtain the `BindingFlags` value? I suppose I could save the value I use in the call to `Type.GetProperty()` and carry it along with the `[Runtime]PropertyInfo` object wherever it goes, but that seems ugly.

I am (still!) using .NET framework 3.5, if that helps. Thanks!

EDIT:

The context of all this is a simple expression solver that gives my users access to a limited set of global objects and some of their properties, in order to create customised notifications with variable information coming from a database. At design time, my users define something like `"Hello, [=Shipment.Recipient.Name]. Your order [=Shipment.Id] is ready for delivery."` and later on, when the notification is rendered, the system outputs *"Hello, Bob. Your order 12345 is ready for delivery"*.

I considered using the `CodeProvider` classes provided by the .NET Framework, but I need my code to run in a medium trust environment without Visual Studio installed, and I also do not want to expose too much functionality, because there is a possibility that third parties will have access to the notification designer, and I do not want anybody injecting any dangerous code in the notifications.

So, instead, I have written a simple expression parser/compiler/interpreter that provides the functionality I want to expose and no more; that is, property reading, string concatenation, basic arithmetic and date/time operations. The expressions are analysed for consistency, types are checked and a pseudo-assembler code is generated that can be serialised and stored as a sequence of bytes to be later recreated and executed upon a specific set of object instances, in order to yield the final expression result.

Parsing/compilation and execution happen in different contexts, at different times, with different sessions and maybe even on different machines, so I need to be able to recreate call chains from scratch as series of PropertyInfo objects from a base Type object obtained through its fully qualified name.

So far, I only examine `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` properties when I analyse call chains, but I see how I might, in the future, extend the implementation to include things like static properties, or whatever. I hence prefer not to assume any specific set of binding flags and I do not want to waste time discovering it during expression execution either, since I know its value at the time of compilation; I would rather store it in the serialised program so that I can pass it directly to `Type.GetProperty()` when I reconstruct the call chain.

But the code where I serialise the compiled expression is definitely not in the same local scope as the code where I check whether some fragment of text entered by the user is a valid property in the current call chain, so by the time I need the value I have long ago forgotten the parameters passed to the `Type.GetProperties()` function I called during analysis. That is how I find myself with a `RuntimePropertyInfo` containing the value I want to store, but unable to reach it because the .NET compiler thinks it is an instance of its base class `PropertyInfo`, that does not contain the `BindingFlags` property. Very frustrating.

If I have to store the parameters used somewhere else, so that I can retrieve them during program serialization, then I will. But if I could simply cast the object to an instance of `RuntimePropertyInfo` and read its `BindingFlags` property, my life would be a little bit easier.

Comment: It is not the way it works, the time that BindingFlags matters is when you *create* the PropertyInfo object.  Once you have it you can use its members, typically GetValue(), maybe SetValue().  You do have to have *some* kind of idea what type of object or value the property stores.  If you don't then you can't use Get/SetValue() correctly.  Reflection isn't otherwise a back-door around internal implementation details that are inaccessible or undocumented.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Yes, I know the value matters when the PropertyInfo object is created, that is why I want to retrieve it. I want to store it elsewhere so that I can use it later on, when I want to recreate the same PropertyInfo object from another instance of the same Type object. Any ideas?

Comment: Very hard to guess why you'd want to "retrieve it" when it is your own code that specified the BindingFlags.  Or why it matters.  "Another instance of the same Type object" does not make sense either, there is only ever *one* instance of a Type object for a specific type.  It describes a type, not an object.  The only way anybody is going to give you a helpful answer is when you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.  You only tried to describe an approach and it doesn't sound kosher at all.

Comment: The PI will behave the same way regardless of what BindingFlags were used to retrieve it. So you can reobtain the object by simply storing it's declaring type and name.; Decompiling the code it looks like the m_bindingFlags member is an internal optimization to help with cache lookups. Looks like a hack, the BF should be stored in the cache and not in the PI.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments, @HansPassant. I have provided some context as to why I might need such a thing.

Comment: Can you respond to my comment as well? Different PI objects with differing BF member will behave identically. You can *always* obtain an equivalent PI just by its declaring type and (exact) name.

Comment: Sorry @usr, I am in the middle of a few things; thank you very much for your insight. I am not as worried about the PI objects behaving differently as I am about the function Type.GetProperty() returning null due to an incorrect combination of BindingFlags, but I will try without binding flags, as you suggest. After all, I may be trying to solve a non-existent problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you just specify the exact name and Public|Private|Inst|Static it will find any property. The BF are just search options, you can just allow everything. Even if this does not work for some reason you can go `GetP(Public) ?? GetP(Private)`. It's not possible to have multiple properties with the same name (except for indexers I think...).

Answer (score 0):

```
var bindingFlags = 
ReflectionUtil.GetPrivatePropertyValue<BindingFlags>(propertyInfo, "BindingFlags");


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using HQ.Util.General.DynamicProperties;

namespace HQ.Util.General.Reflection
{
    public class ReflectionUtil
    {
        // ******************************************************************
        public static BindingFlags BindingFlagsAll = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;
        public static BindingFlags BindingFlagsPublic = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        public static BindingFlags BindingFlagsAllButNotStatic = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Will also set public property. Will set value in instance of any base class in hierarchy.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        public static void SetPrivatePropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName, object value)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = GetPropertyInfoRecursive(obj.GetType(), propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (pi == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(propertyName, string.Format("Property {0} was not found in Type {1}", propertyName, obj.GetType().FullName));
            }
            pi.SetValue(obj, value);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Will also get public property. Will get value in instance of any base class in hierarchy.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T GetPrivatePropertyValue<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = GetPropertyInfoRecursive(obj.GetType(), propertyName);
            if (pi == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(propertyName, string.Format("Property {0} was not found in Type {1}", propertyName, obj.GetType().FullName));
            }

            return (T)pi.GetValue(obj);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// This is mainly used to look for private properties recursively because "FlattenHierarchy" is only applied on static members. 
        /// And also because private property could only be gotten for declared class type, not hierarchy.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <param name="bindingFlags"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoRecursive(Type type, string propertyName, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName, bindingFlags);
            if (pi == null && type.BaseType != null)
            {
                pi = GetPropertyInfoRecursive(type.BaseType, propertyName, bindingFlags);
            }

            return pi;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! But how does this help?

Comment: I mean... the problem is not getting some private "BindingFlags" up the class hierarchy from PropertyInfo, but getting it from an undeclared class derived from PropertyInfo.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem. In fact it seems pretty complex. Personnaly, with what I understand, I would potentially used Roslyn (I did it in oder to include Macros in my own code). It is relatively easy now that Roslyn is more stable (but require pretty large dependencies). Otherwise I would simply parse the code without ever compiling it, only interpret it which would be slower but safer. Sorry I can't help much. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

how about a hack like this:

```
PropertyInfo propinfo;

bool isinstance  = Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance).Contains(propinfo);
bool ispublic  = Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).Contains(propinfo);
```